# How to get list of lists of decreasing size from n to one

Tags: python

I want for a number `n` for there to be a nested list containing sublists that start off at length `n` and decrease to length one. If `n` was `4`, the list would be:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0,], [0]]
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
triangle = []
for i in range(n):
    for k in range(i):
        triangle.append(0)
```

That just gave out for input `n = 5`:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: You will need to make a new list between the inner and outer `for` loop and append to that. Then append this list to the main one. Alternatively, just `[[0]*m for m in range(n, 0, -1)]`?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to mantain your code form, you just use this function:

```py
def get_triangle_list(n):
    triangle_list = []
    for i in range(n, 0, -1):
        tmp_list = []
        for k in range(i):
            tmp_list.append(0)
        triangle_list.append(tmp_list)
    return triangle_list

print(get_triangle_list(4))
```

and output will be:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0], [0]]
```

But, as suggested by [@Abhijit Sarkar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/839733/abhijit-sarkar), you can obtain the same output in smarter and more efficent way using list comprehension like

```py
triangles = [[0] * x for x in range(n, 0, -1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n = 4
triangles = [[0] * x for x in range(n, 0, -1)]

print(triangles)
```